# Unwrap element without jQuery and using createElement

Tags: javascript

With jQuery it's really easy unwrap elements but with pure JS it's not that easy. I spent the last 2 hours trying but no result. I read ALL the topics on Google and SO and no solution. Most of them use jQuery, others are not cross browsing.

So far I have:

```
    var temp = document.createElement("div");
    temp.innerHTML = "HERE COMES A COMPLEX HTML WITH SEVERAL DIVS, SPANS...";
    document.insertNode(temp);
```

The problem is that my HTML code is being inserted with the "div" surrounding it. I need to remove this div from being parent. I made an attempt that maybe is a clue but so far not helping:

Instead of:

```
document.insertNode(temp);
```

I use

document.insertNode(temp.firstChild);

The problem is that only the firstChild is being inserted in the document.

You may say it is useless what I need but it's not! I have a [website](http://www.sitepor500.com.br) which (as you can see) is veeery loaded, full of css effects and as you scroll down the page it gets more loaded and loaded. If I could unwrap this outer div it would be great since I will insert at least 120 commponents in the website.

I am optimizing this websit traffic to balance it, so I will make it all script. There will be minimal html. All the images and remaining divs will be inserted using this method, so at the end I will not want 120 useless divs in the DOM that could have been removed. I have my reasons so I am here not to discuss the why, but I need to unwrap the div.

OBS: there is method that is using outerHTML = innerHTML but it repaints all the page everytime it's called. So it's a terrible idea.

Comment: I cannot use jQuery cause I will remove it from the optimized website. I will only use pure JS.

Comment: Use a loop, and insert `.firstChild`s until there are none left in `temp`. As in `while(temp.firstChild) document.body.appendChild(temp.firstChild);`

Comment: @CrazyTrain as I sayed I will insert around 120 elements on page, and looping every element to find it's child will consume a lot of time and cpu. The goal here is optimize, and it will make the website render worse than it already is

Comment: Instead of a temp div you could use document fragments, check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment

Comment: Have you discovered a performance issue? As @elclanrs suggested, you can use a document fragment, but you'll still need a `temp` if you want to use `.innerHTML`. Even with a fragment, there can still be issues depending on the browser.

Comment: @elclanrs I took a look in your link and it may be good but did you click on MOBILE tab under BROWSER COMPATIBILITY? It does not say if it's cross browsing. I need it to be cross. Do you have any idea how I can check the compatility of the fragment in mobiles?

Comment: May be: var text = document.createTextNode("same text");document.body.appendChild(text);

Comment: That's a really absurd that JS does not provide someway to remove a parent element without having to repaint the whole children! It should be easy... maybe there is somewhay that I did not discover yet...

Comment: @Mihail your answer is good but I cannot create a text node. As I sayed I will inject complex HTML in the page, not only text nodes.

Comment: I can't tell if you're unwrapping elements currently in the DOM, or not. If not, and you're just creating new elements, then why use `.innerHTML`? Why not use DOM methods? And again, have you actually encountered a performance issue?

Comment: @CrazyTrain I have all the HTML of the 120 elements ready. Unfortunatelly I cannot dismount then and insert one by one. It would be the best idea, sure, but I cant dismount the HTML. And about your second question, the problem of setting the innerHTML is that when it already inserted about 40 elements the mouse freezes for about 20 seconds till finishing inserting the reamaining nodes. I know that cause I made a console.log as each node was added with the new Date() and after the 40th node it takes a lot to insert the next nodes even if they are small!

Comment: @amandanovaes documentfragments are compatible with all modern and slightly older browsers as well, including mobile browsers.

Comment: @amandanovaes: How are you inserting the HTML when you do it one by one? Are you doing something like `elem.innerHTML += "(the html content)"` in a loop?

Comment: @CrazyTrain No, I am using insertNode ,node by node. It is the best alternative but far too complicated. I have all the 120 elements saved in .html files, like: footer.html, sidebar.html.... I just want to insert the content of the html file in the DOM whithout having to use innerHTML JUST to remove the parent div. If to remove  a child I dont need to use innerHTML and repaint the whole page, why to remove a parent is it so complicated and costly (expensive)?

Comment: why not just use jquery? your issues doesn't seem to be page loading, but rather insertion of DOM elements. jquery will definitely help with that. Also, your question doesn't make sense. if you don't want to insert it into the div, why are you doing so? just insert it directly to body, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody’s still interested, it’s possible to get all element’s contents with `Range.selectNodeContents()`, then extract into a DocumentFragment with `Range.extractContents()`. After that, nothing stops you from using `ParentNode.replaceChild`, as DocumentFragment is an ordinary Node.

Not sure about performance, but at least there’re no individual nodes being extracted and inserted, should be pretty fast.